# How may I use apps without installing it?

Tags: applications, installation

Is there any way to copy and paste some files and directories and install an app without using package installer from one tab to other.
Android Version 6.0.1
Tablet Lenovo Tab x103f

Comment: Unless you're rooted, this might not be doable.

Comment: I gave rooted my both the devices

Answer (score 0):

Instant application can be used without installation [check this out](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/.)

Comment: Note that this may only work for apps that support Google Play Instant, which not all apps support.